# C 40bit byte swap (endian)

Tags: c, swap, endianness, bit-fields

I'm reading/writing a binary file in *little-endian* format from *big-endian* using C and bswap_{16,32,64} macros from byteswap.h for byte-swapping.

All values are read and written correctly, except a bit-field of 40 bits.

The `bswap_40` macro doesn't exist and I don't know how do it or if a better solution is possible.

Here is a small code showing this problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <byteswap.h>

#define bswap_40(x) bswap_64(x)

struct tIndex {
  uint64_t val_64;
  uint64_t val_40:40;
} s1 = { 5294967296, 5294967296 };

int main(void)
{
    // write swapped values
    struct tIndex s2 = { bswap_64(s1.val_64), bswap_40(s1.val_40) };
    FILE *fp = fopen("index.bin", "w");
    fwrite(&s2, sizeof(s2), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    // read swapped values
    struct tIndex s3;
    fp = fopen("index.bin", "r");
    fread(&s3, sizeof(s3), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    s3.val_64 = bswap_64(s3.val_64);
    s3.val_40 = bswap_40(s3.val_40);

    printf("val_64: %" PRIu64 " -> %s\n", s3.val_64, (s1.val_64 == s3.val_64 ? "OK" : "Error"));
    printf("val_40: %" PRIu64 " -> %s\n", s3.val_40, (s1.val_40 == s3.val_40 ? "OK" : "Error"));

    return 0;
}
```

That code is compiled with:

> gcc -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
>   swap_40.c -o swap_40

How can I define `bswap_40` macro for read and write these values of 40 bits doing byte-swap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By defining `bswap_40` to be the same as `bswap_64`, you're swapping 8 bytes instead of 5.  So if you start with this:

```
00 00 00 01 02 03 04 05
```

You end up with this:

```
05 04 03 02 01 00 00 00
```

Instead of this:

```
00 00 00 05 04 03 02 01
```

The simplest way to handle this is to take the result of `bswap_64` and right shift it by 24:

```
#define bswap_40(x) (bswap_64(x) >> 24)
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

I got better performance writing this macro (comparing with my initial code, this produced less assembly instructions):

```
#define bswap40(s)                                                \
  ((((s)&0xFF) << 32) | (((s)&0xFF00) << 16) | (((s)&0xFF0000)) | \
   (((s)&0xFF000000) >> 16) | (((s)&0xFF00000000) >> 32))
```

use:

```
s3.val_40 = bswap40(s3.val_40);
```

... but it might be an optimizer issue. I thinks they should be optimized to the same thing.

**Original Post**

I love dbush's answer better... I was about to write this:

```
static inline void bswap40(void* s) {
  uint8_t* bytes = s;
  bytes[0] ^= bytes[3];
  bytes[1] ^= bytes[2];
  bytes[3] ^= bytes[0];
  bytes[2] ^= bytes[1];
  bytes[0] ^= bytes[3];
  bytes[1] ^= bytes[2];
}
```

It's a destructive inline function for switching the bytes...

Comment: Thanks, an optimized version is funny.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm reading/writing a binary file in little-endian format from big-endian using C and bswap_{16,32,64} macros from byteswap.h for byte-swapping.

Suggest a different way of approaching this problem: Far more often, code needs to read a file in a known endian format and then convert to the code's endian.  This *may* involve a byte swap, it may not  the trick is to write code that works under all conditions.

```
 unsigned char file_data[5];
 // file data is in big endidan
 fread(file_data, sizeof file_data, 1, fp);

 uint64_t y = 0;
 for (i=0; i<sizeof file_data; i++) {
   y <<= 8;
   y |= file_data[i];
 }

 printf("val_64: %" PRIu64 "\n", y);
```

---

`uint64_t val_40:40;` is not portable.  Bit ranges on types other that `int`, `signed int`, `unsigned` are not portable and have implementation specified behavior.

BTW: Open the file in *binary* mode:

```
// FILE *fp = fopen("index.bin", "w");
FILE *fp = fopen("index.bin", "wb");
```